# What does "beach you off" mean?

Tags: language-explanation, barbie-2023

Ken 1 was injured while trying to surf on a board:

> Ken 2: Looks like this beach was a little too much beach for you, Ken.
>
> Ken 1: If I wasn't severely injured, I would **beach you off** right now,
> Ken.
>
> Ken 2: I'll **beach off** with you any day, Ken.

Here is the scene from *Barbie* (2023):

What does "beach you off" mean ?

Comment: Ugh. I'm not explaining this one...

Comment: A beach-off is like [a walk-off](https://youtu.be/sbnCoQ75RuM?si=j5JILZWjdMOVoF-P&t=136), but on the beach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "beach off" is (in context) similar to a [dance-off](https://youtu.be/jaaJyAjvajo?si=DdIadqhEoX9_TDAX&t=20) or a [walk-off](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbnCoQ75RuM&t=136s), an informal competition between two similarly skilled individuals in order to demonstrate superiority.

> The Dance-Off is a type of contest, but rather than one anyone can
> enter, it's a form of duel between two or more mutual antagonists,
> either singular or more commonly groups.
>
> <sub><sup>https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DanceOff</sup></sub>

Ken and Ken are going to demonstrate their various skills as beachgoers (presumably activities like surfing, frisbee, sunbathing, etc) in order to demonstrate that they're the *beachiest* individual.

---

Out of universe we're able to laugh at the clear double entendre. It sounds like '[beat you off](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/beat-off#:%7E:text=2.%C2%A0,US%2C%20Slang)', slang for masturbating.

Comment: Also phonemically similar to the term "bitch", which is implies weakness or subordination in this context. See [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitch_off) also. "Bitch off" is also a more recent term for what I know as "catfight" - a fight between two women usually characterized by hair-pulling and scratching and slapping. Given the feminist nature of the Barbie (2023) movie and the role reversal for Kens and Barbies cf. our world, it might well be intended in this context.